Ubuntu 22.04 LTS very unstable on my new HP Laptop
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my new HP 255 G10 notebook but it is very unstable and randomly freezes on a daily basis. Also it has other erratic behavior. For example, randomly the mouse and keyboard stop responding, the screen goes black, then after a few seconds everything comes back to normal again. Occasionally however it does not, and I would need to power off the system and re-start.
Another very irritating behavior is when the OS closes my Netbeans and Skype with no apparent reason. This happens at least one or twice a day.


What do your logs say about these problems?

May  3 12:19:42 nlaLaptop kernel: [17661.567176] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] ERROR ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=14835, emitted seq=14837
May  3 12:19:42 nlaLaptop kernel: [17661.567569] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] ERROR Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
May  3 12:19:42 nlaLaptop kernel: [17661.567827] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!

The Ryzen 5 7520U uses a Zen 2 architecture with the codename Mendocino and features Radeon 610M integrated graphics.
The Radeon integrated graphics on your HP 255 G10 notebook is weak and can't keep up with the workload. One solution is to connect an external discrete graphics processor to improve graphics processing performance. This would be brute force solution to the unstable and randomly freezing problem, but there are also more balanced solutions available.
Alternatively you can install an application called preload from the default Ubuntu repositories with sudo apt install preload.
Preload monitors applications that users run, and by analyzing this data, predicts what applications users might run, and fetches those binaries and their dependencies into memory for faster startup times.
Do you have swap? free will tell you. If not, you need between 1xRAM
(8 GB) and 2xRAM (16 GB). Swap space must be contiguous, not fragmented. Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab

Do you have swap? free will tell you.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Swap space must be contiguous, not fragmented. Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab.

I have 2.1GB swap

That's a normal size for an automatically resizable swap file, so maybe you don't need more than 2.1GB swap.

"The Radeon integrated graphics on your HP 255 G10 notebook is weak and can't keep up with the workload." Windows is working perfectly on it however. In the past it used to be the other way round. Computers struggling to run Windows used to run like a breeze with Ubuntu. How things change!
